# Sqoop Export failed to Netezza Error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.InterruptedException

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, netezza

I am exporting the data from HDFS to Netezza using sqoop , and there are many jobs running in parallel. few of them failed with the following error

causing the Sqoop job to fail. Can anyone please help me with this issue.
I have taken care of all the permissions and ownership of the tables in Netezza.

> > > **18/03/13 18:08:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : 
> > >            attempt_1517179256891_920980_m_000005_2, Status : FAILED
> > >            Error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.InterruptedException**
> > >
> > > at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1463)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1398)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
> > >       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.delete(Unknown Source)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:585)
> > >       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> > >       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> > >       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> > >       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:291)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:203)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:185)
> > >       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.delete(Unknown Source)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.delete(DFSClient.java:2094)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:815)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:811)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.delete(DistributedFileSystem.java:811)
> > >       at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileUploader.uploadFilesToDFS(FileUploader.java:58)
> > >       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.netezza.NetezzaExternalTableExportMapper.run(NetezzaExternalTableExportMapper.java:249)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
> > >       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> > >       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1865)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
> > >       Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
> > >       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:404)
> > >       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.sendRpcRequest(Client.java:1094)
> > >       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1457)
> > >               ... 26 more

Comment: You need to add the error as text, so that it is searchable and readable.

Comment: @WaqasBukharyI have updated the question with the error.